# How to hide keyboard on dialog dismiss

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I have an `Activity` with single `Fragment` on it. There is one `EditText` on the fragment.

The keyboard is popping up as soon the fragment is shown, however I managed to block it setting in the manifest android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

However, there also is a button, which opens a dialog with another EditText.

I have a method that automatically closes the keyboard on dialog dismiss.

```
public static void closeInput(final View caller) {      
    caller.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) caller.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(caller.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
        }
    });
}
```

The method is not a pretty hack and there is something wrong about it. Dialog's `EditText` has `inputType="numberDecimal"`. The `closeInput()` seems to be not closing the keyboard, only changing it to the default alphabetical state.

What is going on here?

Comment: What about at the creation of your dialog you call this method and then again when the dialog is dismissed?

Comment: why would I call closeInput on dialog creation? At the time no input is visible

Comment: Oh, I thought that might have been when the first and second keyboard appeared.

Comment: Oh, I see it now, when the dialog is dismissed the fragment is creating the second keyboard. Why not just call the method to hide your keyboard in the `onResume()` of your fragment?

Comment: onResume() is not beeing called after dialog dismiss

Comment: From my understanding, it should be called since the fragment is regaining focus.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: Actually I did. Check the answer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In my case I used method:

```
public static void closeInput(final View caller) {  
    caller.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) caller.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(caller.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

It was refusing to work properly because of activity settings in Manifest, if I recall you can't have `android:windowSoftInputMode="any_of_these"` set

Comment: Regarding «if I recall you can't have android:windowSoftInputMode="any_of_these"» - I managed to get all working while having `windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing|stateAlwaysHidden"` and using `setSoftInputMode(SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN|SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);`

Comment: In my tests, you don't need `postDelayed(runnable, 100)`. The `100` seems fragile. You can just use `post(runnable)` instead (works for me). Can anyone confirm/disprove that?

Comment: I tried many solutions and this was the only one that worked. I was able to remove the delay and it caused no issues.

Comment: "you can't have android:windowSoftInputMode set" - this was the key point for me, bizarrely removing "stateHidden" fixed keyboard not hiding!

Answer (score 14):

From fragments onCreateView() method you can do this:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
```

> It will automatically hide soft keyboard on Dismiss of Dialog

Comment: it will be closed if the activity is declared with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` too

Comment: The only solution that worked in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

in BaseDialog.java

```
protected void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm.isActive()) {
        imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Searched for days how to do this. Tried everything in every forum, finally this closed keyboard on dialog exit. Thanks

Comment: Working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateVisible"
```

I deleted `stateVisible`:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

And `onDismiss()`, no need to call `hideSoftInput` method.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, solution was to put keyboard hide in dialog dismiss

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
            if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Struggling with this issue and after reviewing the answers here, most seem to actually work. Since it was ***not desired to use a class rather just a builder***, the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36422411/1815624 is not a workable solution.

Realizing others may have this same issue, an answer is being derived from both:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393446/1815624 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/32648971/1815624

So the combination answer is grabbing the view from the fragment itself:

*(Anyone got a reason not to?)*

```
void closeKeyboard(final View caller){
    caller.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) caller.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(caller.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
    });
}
```

...

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        closeKeyboard(getView());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

found a simple way to hide dialog keyboard

1. dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
2. call hideKeyboardFromDialogBeforeDismiss() **before dialog dismiss**, may be on cancel button clicked event, **shouldn't call in onDismiss or onCancelListener**

   ```
   binding.cancelBtn.setOnClickListener {       
       STSystemUtil.hideKeyboardFromDialogBeforeDismiss(dialog = dialog) 
       binding.root.postDelayed({ dialog?.dismiss() }, 200)
   }
   ```

```
    @JvmStatic
    @JvmOverloads
    fun getInputMethodManager(context: Context? = STInitializer.application()): InputMethodManager? {
        return context?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager?
    }

    /*
     * 注意: 如果 dialog 包含一个或者多个EditText, 点击外部(canceledOnTouchOutside==true)不会隐藏已经显示的输入法弹框, 且通过点击取消按钮必须先隐藏输入法弹框再延时 dismiss, 因为在 onCancel/onDismiss 中 dialog?.currentFocus?.windowToken 必然已经是 null, 且 inputMethodManager?.isActive 必然是 false
     * ----> canceledOnTouchOutside = false
     * ----> binding.cancelBtn.setOnClickListener {
     *          STSystemUtil.hideKeyboardFromDialogBeforeDismiss(dialog)
     *          binding.root.postDelayed({ dialog?.dismiss() }, 200)
     *       }
     */
    @JvmStatic
    @JvmOverloads
    fun hideKeyboardFromDialogBeforeDismiss(context: Context? = STInitializer.application(), dialog: Dialog? = null) {
        val inputMethodManager: InputMethodManager? = getInputMethodManager(context)
        if (dialog == null) {
            if (inputMethodManager?.isActive == true) {
                inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
            }
        } else {
            inputMethodManager?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(dialog.currentFocus?.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog)
    val window = getDialog()?.window
    if (window != null) {
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView).hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add explanation to your answer to make others understand your solution.