# How to show/hide the Android Soft Keyboard in dialog?

Tags: android

In my application custom dialog is in BaseExpandableListAdapter class.
In dialog I have two edit text. First is name and its mandatory. And second is address its optional. And two buttons OK and cancel. When Dialog shows I want to show keyboard with request focus for edit text name. After clicking of OK button Soft Keyboard should get hide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard?rq=1

Comment: go to this :[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard?rq=1)

Comment: show what you have tried and whats not working.

Comment: Best answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393446/1164529

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(_context);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.prompts);
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

final EditText name = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.name);
final EditText add = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.add);

Button btnok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
Button btncancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);

 btnAddExpList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {           dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);  
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 18):

on click of ok button write the below code:-

```
  final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    final EditText text = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.nameField);

   Button mOkBtn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.okBtn);


    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
   mOkBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
           imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(text.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
```

Define context as Context context=this.

Answer (score 5):

Use following code to hide keyboard

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Use following code to show keyboard

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this function:

```
public void hideKeyboard() {
    if (getDialog().getCurrentFocus() != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getDialog().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}
```

I wish it be useful

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
    private fun showCustomDialog() {

        // Normal dialog stuff
        // -----
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity as Context) 
        val customLayout = View.inflate(context, R.layout.dialog_layout, null)
        val editText: EditText = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.edit_text)
        // -----

        // Get a hold of the inpoutMethodManager here
        val imm = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

        builder.setTitle(getText(R.string.dialog_title))
        builder.setView(customLayout)
        builder.setPositiveButton(getText(R.string.action_confirm)) { _, _ ->
            // Hide the soft keyboard here after the positive button onclick
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.windowToken, 0)
            /*
             * Do your logic here for the positive click
             * ....
             */
        }
        builder.setNegativeButton(getText(R.string.action_cancel)) { dialog, _ ->
            // Also hide the soft keyboard if the user clicked negative button
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.windowToken, 0)
            /*
             * Do your logic here for the negative click
             * ....
             */
            dialog.cancel()
        }
        // added not cancelable for the dialog since it might mess with the keyboard hiding
        builder.setCancelable(false)
        builder.show()

        // make sure you call this to request focus, or else the hiding might not work...
        editText.requestFocus()
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your activity

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        View v = getCurrentFocus();
        boolean ret = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

        if (v instanceof EditText) {
            View w = getCurrentFocus();
            int scrcoords[] = new int[2];
            w.getLocationOnScreen(scrcoords);
            float x = event.getRawX() + w.getLeft() - scrcoords[0];
            float y = event.getRawY() + w.getTop() - scrcoords[1];

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && (x < w.getLeft() || x >= w.getRight() || y < w.getTop() || y > w.getBottom()) ) { 

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    return ret;
    }
```

Comment: just paste at your activity class this as it is dude

Comment: basically is it ontouch method override and in this i put code for dismiss soft keyboard

Comment: just paste this as it is in your activity class its a @Override methos

Answer (score 1):

Use it.

```
protected void hideKeyboardDialog(Dialog dialog){
    View view = dialog.getView();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Show the `KeyBoard` when you show the `Dialog` and close the `KeyBoard` when you press `OK` button as below...

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_error) + ":" + errorCode);
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Message");
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

          imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);       }
});

alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

      }
});

AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();

imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. When Dialog shows I want to show keyboard with request focus for edit text name.

This is easy as you yourself answered it. Add `<requestfocus/>` to your EditText via xml or `editText.requestFocus();` via code before you show the dialog.

1. After clicking of OK button Soft Keyboard should get hide.

This can be achieved in two ways, depending upon what you are doing on click of your OK button.

a. If you are starting a new Activity - Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` to this activity in the Manifest, so everytime the activity starts keyboard will be hidden unless you call it.

b. If you are on the same page - call the below method.

```
    private void hideSoftKeyBoard() {
            try {
                // hides the soft keyboard when the drawer opens
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

In case **getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken()** gives error then pass any View to it (you can track this via the try catch block) where View could be anything, a Button, EditText etc of your Activity (`myButton..getWindowToken()`).